# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Automatically complete renewal orders and Subscription status

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

I am working on a site which uses WooCommerce Subscriptions and WooCommerce Memberships. It sells subscriptions which renew annually.

The only payment gateway being used is  Cheque (renamed to Pay via Invoice), so all renewals are manual renewals. An invoice is sent to the customer (outside of WooCommerce) and the store owners mark the order as Completed in admin when payment has been made.

The Subscription status is tied to the latest order status:

- if the order is completed, the sub is Active.
- if the order is pending, processing, on hold etc, the sub is On Hold.

As invoices are being sent and processed via an external accounting system, the client wants to have renewal orders automatically complete so that there is no break in membership access for users.

I've looked at similar questions such as here and I'm running into similar issues.

[Change subscription status to active based on order id WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221432/change-subscription-status-to-active-based-on-order-id-woocommerce)

I've tested the hook `woocommerce_new_order` and can see it's firing for all orders, including renewals.

Using `wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order()`, it's possible to pass `'renewal'` as an `order_type` to test if the given order is a renewal or a new customer.

I have a very small bit of code to check the new order, update it if applicable, and update the subscription status afterwards. However, it seems that my first `if` block is being skipped over - it always runs to the code in the `else` block.

Additionally, if I move the lines to update the order and sub status to the `else` block (so it does update all orders), the order status updates but the sub stays as On Hold.

I'm guessing there must be some trigger that is usually called if updating the order from admin or via payment that isn't firing, but I can't see from the docs what it would be.

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong here, please?

```
<?php

/**
 * Autocomplete Renewal Orders
 */

function ctz_autocomplete_renewal_order($order_id) {
  
  /**
   * Check if the order is associated with a subscription 
   * 
   * WC Subscriptions gives us a function to obtain the related orders for a subscription in an array. The second parameter allows us to retrieve only renewal orders.
   * 
   * We can use this function to check if the given order ID is for a new customer order or an existing customer's renewal. 
   * 
   * If this array returns blank, it's a first order, and should be skipped over.
   */
  
  // Get related Subscriptions 
  
  $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($order_id, array('order_type' => 'renewal'));
  
  if(is_array($subscriptions) && !empty($subscriptions) ) :                                 
    
    // This is a renewal order - change the status 
  
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    $order->update_status( 'completed');
    
    $order->save();
    
    // Check and update the subscription status
    
    activate_subscriptions_for_order($order);
    
    // Log the change
    
    $message = $order_id . " Renewal automatically completed.";
  
    ctz_custom_logs('autorenewals', $message);
  
  else :
    
  // This is a new order - leave unchanged 
  
    $message = $order_id . " Initial order - status unchanged.";
  
    ctz_custom_logs('autorenewals', $message);
  
  endif;
 
}

add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'ctz_autocomplete_renewal_order', 11, 1);

?>
```

FYI the logging function I'm using is just for debugging and records the given message to a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('wcs_renewal_order_created', 'wcs_after_create_renewal_order', 10, 2);

function wcs_after_create_renewal_order($renewal_order, $subscription) {

    // Set the current renewal order as completed.
    $renewal_order->update_status('completed');
    $renewal_order->add_order_note( __( 'Renewal automatically processed' ) );

    // Set the corresponding subscription as active.
    $subscription->update_status('active');
    return $renewal_order;
}
```

The hook `wcs_renewal_order_created` is fired only after a renewal order is created. Simply add the code snippet above into your active theme `functions.php` file.

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you so much. I hadn't seen that filter - so much cleaner then messing around with a hook. I noticed that the order notes aren't as clear when doing this (says "awaiting payment"). Is it possible to add a private note when the order is completed - something like "Renewal automatically processed."?

Comment: I'm so glad you added this piece of code saving me hours! However, it's not working for me. Any idea as to why that could be? I'm about to try and add some logging, but it's a pain because I have to wait for another subscription to process (I have a test one processing every 24 hours lol). Also, would be great if you know how to force process a renewal! My client has a lot of clients set up for renewal so I'm walking on egg shells in the code here. Duplicating environment but test subscriptions not working for some reason 

Comment: I'm not sure if you still need help processing renewals for testing, but if you (or any future readers) do, you can go to the subscription page, then under Subscription Actions, select 'process renewal'. Make sure you do this on a test website - you don't want to accidentally cause subs to renew for real!